# Как удалить CefSharp C# с формы?

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

У меня появился вопрос, как я могу удалить браузер с формы?
Создаю таким образом

```
_cefSettings = new CefSettings
{
   CachePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "cache",
};
_cefSettings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-gpu");

Cef.Initialize(_cefSettings);
CefSharpSettings.ShutdownOnExit = false;

_browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://bitly.com/")
{
   Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
   LifeSpanHandler = new BrowserSettingClose(),
};
tabPage3.Controls.Add(_browser);
```

Но когда пытаюсь вызвать `Cef.Shutdown()`, то форма закрывается. И возможно ли после успешного удаления, создать его вновь, без перезагрузки формы?

Comment: `tabPage3.Controls.Remove(_browser);`

Comment: Почитайте документацию на CefSharp, там будет прямым текстом сказано, что "`Cef.Initialize()` и `Cef.Shutdown()` должны быть вызваны **только раз** на процесс", другим языком, эти методы вы можете вызывать только один раз за все время работы приложения.

Answer (score 0):

Сначала создаёте например панель, потом ставите вкладку браузера на эту панель, а когда захотите удалить вкладку, сначала удалите с формы панель и уже после этого вызовите метод Dispose для вкладки браузера. Вот пример кода который создаёт вкладку и сразу же удаляет, без закрытия формы.

```
var panel=new Panel(); //создать панель
Controls.Add(panel); //добавить панель на форму
var browser=new ChromiumWebBrowser(""); //создать вкладку браузера
panel.Controls.Add(browser); //добавить вкладку на панель
Controls.Remove(panel); //удалить панель. Если эту строку убрать, то форма будет закрываться на следующей строке
browser.Dispose(); //удалить вкладку
```